# How can I describe the difference between these two value passing styles?

Tags: javascript, c, function, parameters, parameter-passing

This is what I understand to be pass by reference in C (note: I am not a C programmer):

```c
void foo(int* x) { // The value of the memory address passed into `foo` is copied into parameter `x`
  *x = 1; // The memory address x is dereferenced(?) and the value at that location overwritten
}

int main() {
  int a = 0;
  foo(&a); // The value of the (starting?) memory address associated with `a` is found and supplied as an argument to the function call
  // `a` is now `1`
}
```

In this way, regardless of the type of `x` (even if it is an object (a struct in C?)), changes made to `x` inside `foo` will be reflected in the scope of main, *even if the entire object is replaced*.

In JavaScript, primitives are simply copied around and this is simple enough to reason about.

But for objects, IIUC, the value of their memory address (or equivalent) is supplied to function `foo`, which superficially sounds similar to the C code above. However, if we assign a value to the identifier created by parameter `x`, this is *not* reflected in the scope of `main`.

```js
function foo(x) {
  x = { bam: 'this is bam' }; // The value of the memory address passed into `foo` is copied into parameter `x`
}

function main() {
  let a = { bar: 'this is bar' };
  foo(a); // The value of the memory address associated with `a` is found and supplied as an argument to the function call (?)
  // `a` is unchaged
}
```

JavaScript is pass by value. For objects it is sometimes called pass-by-value-of-the-reference - fair enough - but in the C code above, the value of the reference (OK pointer) is also copied into the function. So how can I describe the differences between pass-by-reference and pass by value? Is the passing of values actually the same, but only the referencing/dereferencing behavior of the two languages different?

Comment: This may still be confusing for you but in C there is no pass by reference. Everything is pass by value. In the first case a pointer is being passed by value. That is, an address is given to the function which allows it to change the thing pointed to by the address.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Can this C code be said to be emulating pass by reference? Or does pass by reference only refer to a behavior built into a language?

Comment: Passing in a pointer is a common way of allowing a function to change an object that is defined outside of it's scope. People unfamiliar with C may consider this to be a form of pass by reference but it's technically not, though it can be used to have much of the same effect. In contrast, C++ does have pass by reference.

Comment: @BenAston  kaylum is totally wrong. In  the terms of C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer. From the C Standard "A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference
to an entity of the referenced type" Each language has its own terms and definitions independent on terms in other languages. It is only low-qualified programmers mix terms used in C++ or other languages with terms used in C.

Comment: Does pass by reference _necessarily_ enable the callee to modify the complete contents (even replacing it) of the memory location pointed at by the supplied  reference? I ask because JavaScript does not have this capability (although you can modify the object itself), and this would make sense because JS is pass by value (IIUC).

Comment: Re: *"Does pass by reference necessarily enable the called function to modify the complete contents"* - in terms of language semantics: no, you can very well have a function which takes a pointer to constant: `const int *x`, which is a pointer to memory that must not be modified. In practice: even if `const int *` is used it may very well be casted to `int *` and then used to try and modify the value: whether or not that'll work depends on context, but it's definitely terrible practice.

Comment: Understood. If a memory location is marked as constant, then it stands to reason that it is marked as unchangeable. I am trying to identify the key difference between pass by reference and pass by value-of-the-reference. I know that JS is pass by value-of-the-reference (for objects), and that there exists another concept that is pass by reference, I am trying to tease out the difference.

Comment: @kaylum Do you want to say anything to Vlad´s point of view/statement?

Comment: _"even if the entire object is replaced."_ No that is incorrect. Only if the _entire content_ of the object is replaced. "The entire object" includes the pointer itself. For example: `realloc`. This is an error beginners often make (forgetting to pass a double pointer so the object can be replaced).

Comment: So if I were to change the C in my question to make variable `a` a `struct` (which IIUC is the equivalent of an object), then, from within `foo`, only the _contents_ of the struct would be modifiable, unless I used a double pointer?

Comment: An "object" in terms of the C standard does not mean what you think it means. See [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) paragraph 3.14. If you pass a *pointer to an object*, then you can only modify the object itself. In the case of a `struct`, that means modifying the content of the `struct`. If you use a double pointer, then what you can modify is both the pointer to the object and the object itself.

Comment: Re: @PaulOgilvie *"The entire object" includes the pointer itself.* - it does not, see paragraph 3.14 of the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Comment: @kaylum: Re “People unfamiliar with C may consider this to be a form of pass by reference but it's technically not”: Technically, it is. The C standard says pointers are references (C 2018 6.2.5 20, “A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type.”). The C++ standard defines “reference” to be a specific thing in that language, but that meaning applies only in the context of the C++. It does not nullify the meanings of “reference” in other contexts, which antedate the C++ standard…

Comment: … The fact that a reference is passed by explicit source code instead of implicit does not make it not a reference. The `*` is the dereference operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C passes *everything* by value<sup>1</sup>.  Sometimes those values are pointer values; this is not the same thing as pass by reference.

In a true pass by reference system the formal parameter in the function definition designates the same object as the actual parameter in the function call (assuming the actual parameter isn’t a numeric literal, anyway).  Whether that’s accomplished by using pointers or under the hood or through a different mechanism is a function of the implementation. This is never the case in C.

The *expression* `*x` in `foo` designates the same object as the expression `a` in `main`, but the formal parameter `x` is a separate object from `a`.  The result of the *expression* `&a` is passed by value and stored in the unique object `x`.

```
 x == &a // int * == int *
*x ==  a // int   == int
```

---

1. Arrays are weird.  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  When you pass an array expression as an argument to the function, the function receives a pointer to the first element, not a copy of the entire array.  So unlike other argument types, changes to the contents of an array argument in a function are reflected in the caller.  This is still not true pass by reference, however.  This is just fallout from C’s somewhat unique array semantics.

Comment: Thank you. In C, in order to replace the object associated with `a`, from inside `foo`, I presume I therefore need to use a double pointer? Do pass by reference systems pass an entity (a reference) that encapsulates the equivalent of `*x`, with automatic dereferencing?

Comment: @BenAston: If I understand your question correctly, you can’t replace the object associated with `a` (you can’t unbind and rebind it).  The identifier `a` is bound to that object throughout the object’s lifetime.  That’s just how C works.

Comment: Thank you. If object `a` exists in memory somewhere, say address `0x0001`, I presume identifier `a` associates the name `a` with the memory location `0x0001`. If I pass the address associated with identifier `a` into function `foo` ("pass a pointer-to-`a` into `foo`"), then the address may be dereferenced inside `foo` (`*x`), and the object at location `0x0001` can be modified. But if I pass the address of the address associated with identifier `a` ("pass a pointer to a pointer to `a`"), then, from inside `foo`, can I point `a` at a new location in memory ("a different object")?

Comment: No.  There’s no such thing as an “address of an address”.  You can create an object of pointer type, and take the address of *that* object to get a pointer to a pointer, but you can’t do something like `&&a`.  You cannot bind `a` to a different object in that manner.  C semantics simply don’t allow it.